# Create a parent div for the selected element

Tags: javascript

I want to create a div around the clicked element without affecting the style of the page and i need to remove the inserted parent after some operations. Do anybody have any idea to do like that?

Edit: Please note that i don't want to use any JavaScript library

Comment: As a side-note. You cannot guarantee that the styles will not be effected unless you are in control of the css. For example, if you have a style specifically targeting a set of nested elements then those styles will not be applied as soon as you change that nested order by introducing the `div`.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon Clicked element can be of any type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't guarantee it won't affect styles, but as for the rest, try something like this (inside the click handler function):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var parent = this.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(div, this);
div.appendChild(this);
```

If you're still in the function when you want to remove the new div element:

```
parent.insertBefore(this, div);
parent.removeChild(div);
```

If not, you'll need to reaquire it. Let's assume you have a trigger for that, and `this` is still the clicked element:

```
var div = this.parentNode;
var parent = div.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(this, div);
parent.removeChild(div);
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a `wrap()` function that will do what you want. Guaranteeing that no styles are altered is not possible in general, but if you control the page and/or css it shouldn't be a problem.